# How can I list all slugs categories?

Tags: categories

I need to list all slug categories from a taxonomy portfolio_category.
Like this:

```
the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category', '', ', ' );
```

This returns categories from a single portfolio. I want to return just slug of this.

Comment: I would love to see a plugin for this to list all categories when someone goes to the category slug link, similar to plugins that list all posts for an individual category. This would be a hit I think and good for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
$term = get_term( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category');
$slug = $term->slug;
echo  $slug;
```

Comment: I try this before. But return NULL.

Comment: I think you were trying it on the single portfolio page.
if not let me know where you were trying it.

Answer (score 0):

**Get terms attached to the post**

```
$post_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category');
if( is_array($post_terms) ) {
    $post_terms = array_reduce($post_terms, function($carry, $item){
            $carry[] = $item->slug;
            return $carry;
        }, []);
    echo implode(', ', $post_terms);
}
```

---

**Get all terms**

To retrieve all terms from a given taxonomy, use function `get_terms`. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) you will find info about accepted arguments.

Since WP 4.5:

```
$portfolio_terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category', 
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields' => 'id=>slug',
    'orderby' => 'slug',
]);
if( is_array($portfolio_terms) )
    echo implode(', ', $portfolio_terms);
```

Before WP 4.5:

```
$portfolio_terms = get_terms('portfolio_category', [
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields' => 'id=>slug',
    'orderby' => 'slug',
]);
if( is_array($portfolio_terms) )
    echo implode(', ', $portfolio_terms);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got. 
I use this:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$term = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category');
foreach($term as $simples){
    echo $simples->slug;

}
```